# Unity3D Package Cache errors(?)

Tags: unity-game-engine

After deleting and installing Unity due to a problem it caused me, these errors appeared in the console. I've already tried to reinstall Unity but they won't go away.

[image: The errors]

EDIT: I get these errors in every project I open.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Open your project in Unity first**.

Then follow these steps.

- Go to C:/Users/**Your User Name(Utente for this question)**/AppData/Local/Unity/cache/packages/packages.unity.com (The path that is shown in error)
- Delete all of those folders you see in that **packages.unity.com** folder.
- Go back to Unity & let it recompile it. Your errors must be gone now.

Answer (score 7):

for me clicking reset packages to defaults in advanced of the package manager window

Answer (score 2):

I usually go to the Project Tab and Right Click on the Assets Folder and click "Reimport All".

Depending on wicht version of Unity this could happen more often that you want... f.e. using an Alpha Version.

I find it faster only reimporting than deleting files and importing again.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get rid of all missing packages compilation errors by reimporting all packages:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how, but **updating** the ***Package Manager UI*** worked for me.

> Window -> Package Manager -> Package Manager UI

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noZ_8GQWHbc)

Answer (score -1):

The best option to handle this issue is to remove these (2) folders:

1. ProjectDir/Library/PackageCache
2. ProjectDir/Library/packageManager

Create a new Unity project in the same editor version.

Then copy both above folders from the new project and paste them in the
original projects Library folder.

!Important! Make sure the original project is closed!