# CS0426: The type or namespace name 'InputAction' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to make a 3d game and all im trying to do is to get my character walking around but  i keep getting the "Assets/AnimationAndMovementController.cs(26,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InputAction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" message...

im not entirely sure what to do.

im extremely new to unity and c# sharp so maybe im not making any sense ?

uh here's the code...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Numerics.Vector3;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationAndMovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerInput playerInput;
    CharacterController characterController;

    Vector2 currentMovementInput;
    Vector3 currentMovement;
    bool isMovementPressed;

    void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = new PlayerInput();
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        playerInput.CharacterControls.Move.started += onMovementInput;
        playerInput.CharacterControls.Move.canceled += onMovementInput;
        playerInput.CharacterControls.Move.performed += onMovementInput;
    }


    void onMovementInput (InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        currentMovementInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        currentMovement.x = currentMovementInput.x;
        currentMovement.z = currentMovementInput.y;
        isMovementPressed = currentMovementInput.x != 0 || currentMovementInput.y != 0;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        characterController.Move(currentMovement * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        playerInput.CharacterControls.Enable();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        playerInput.CharacterControls.Disable();
    }
}
```

i really appreciate the help!

Comment: You need `using UnityEngine.InputSystem;` at the top of your file with the other using statements.

Comment: for me this worked : basically it says to re-import your packages
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62107411/10705799

Answer (score 2):

**Suggestions:**

Import input system package if you haven't already (which you should have ofcourse but just in case) then try declaring namespace for input system as

```
Using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
```

Hopefully it will work... happy coding :)

Comment: You are always welcome

Answer (score 0):

just like Sherry said, in your Unity project go to the top right corner and choose

**Window -> Package Manager**

at the top left corner of that window you should change:

**Packages: In Project >>> Packages: Unity Registry**

search for Input System and install.

then you want to create an assembly reference to be able to reference it in your script: Karl_Jones has an excellent answer here
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unityengine-inputsystem-not-found.945820/

- Right click in your project (you can create a new folder called
  Assembly references if you like)
- create new -> Assembly Definition Reference
- click on your newly created Assembly Reference file in your project
- click the box next to **Assembly Definition** in the inspector (it should
  say none)
- search for Unity.InputSystem
- choose it and click **Apply**

Aternatively, you could just regenerate your cs projects like so:

- Go to top right corner of your unity project
- Edit -> Preferences
- choose external tools
- tick **Registry Packages**
- click **Regenerate Project Files**

After all that you can then simply add to the top of your script:

```
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
```